# Can you explain the logic behind this recursive call (with promise) in lambda?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, promise

I've got this sample code below extracted from [here](https://tomgregory.com/recursive-aws-lambda-functions-in-node-js-javascript/) to do recursion in Lambda.

In line 22 (return New Promise...), the function returns a promise back to Lambda to call the function itself (lambda-func). My question is if the first function still needs to wait for the promise to complete why the executions stops?

It's probably a beginners question, but I just don't understand well how Lambda can return and promise and complete at the same time. Shouldn't the first run have to wait for the recursive calls to finish its execution?

Any explanation would be a great help to understand this one :)

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda()
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}
const recursionLimit = 5

exports.handler = async(event) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));

    await sleep(2000);

    event.iteration = event.iteration + 1 || 1
    console.log('Iteration: ' + event.iteration + '\n')

    if (event.iteration <= recursionLimit) {
        var params = {
            FunctionName: 'lambda-func',
            InvocationType: 'Event',
            Payload: JSON.stringify(event)
        };
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)    
                } else {
                    resolve(data)
                }
            })
        });
    }
   return 'Finished executing on iteration ' + event.iteration
};
```

Comment: There is no recursion in the code you posted.

Comment: I missed to explain that the code posted there is from “lambda-func” function. So it’s calling itself for 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant information is in this block...

```
var params = {
    FunctionName: 'lambda-func',
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(event)
};
```

The `InvocationType` above indicates that it was invoked as `Event` (as opposed to `RequestResponse`). Event invocations are executed asynchronously. The `lambda.invoke` call will return without waiting for that invocation to finish.

Reference: [Understanding the Different Ways to Invoke Lambda Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/understanding-the-different-ways-to-invoke-lambda-functions/)